# “a lump the size of a golf ball” or “of the size” or “a golf-ball-sized lump”?

Tags: adjective-phrases, hyphens

**Which one of them is grammatically correct?**

1. a lump the size of a golf ball
2. a lump of the size of a golf ball
3. a golf-ball-sized lump

Which one of them is used more in daily language specifically in UK ?

Comment: Both (1) and (3) are idiomatic in British English. I would hazard a guess that (1) might be more common in spoken language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three choices are grammatical although I'm unsure about the hyphenation in 3. I might write it as "a golf ball-sized lump". As to which one I would prefer, it's a toss up between 1 and 3, I found the following excerpts on the Internet

> Colon polyps are clumps of cells that form on the lining of the colon. They range in size from smaller than a pea to **the size of a golf ball**.

> After an initial diagnosis of mild irritable bowel syndrome, a follow-up colonoscopy found **a golf ball-sized tumor** in the bend of Duff's colon.

> Doctors estimated my **golf ball sized tumor** had been growing for upwards of five or more years.

> My son has been getting allergy shots for about a year now. He is on a 2 week schedule now. […]He sometimes gets **a lump** on his arm **the size of a** golf ball.

Comment: I find (2) awkward'; it has too many 'of's.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  You're right, I meant 1 and 3. Thanks for heads-up